# Calculating Time Differences Between Rows Where the Category Passes Over Midnight

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a dataset that is comparing pain scores and am trying to determine the duration of time that the person is in a particular pain range. I initially created a variable with the difference between timestamps of each pain assessment. The idea is to treat each pain score as constant until the next time pain is assessed. This works well, until a pain score is performed after midnight. For example, if a pain score is performed at 2000, then at 0200, time difference for the previous pain score will be 6 hours instead of 4 hours. Hence, for some days, I am getting more than 24 hours of pain score results.

I would like to have the time for each day be 24 hours, and have the previous day pain score carried over into the new day. Does anybody have any ideas?

I have included a dummy dataset that is similar to what I am using.

```
library(tidyverse)



  df <-
  tibble(
    patient_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1),
    time = lubridate::as_datetime(c("2022-01-04 02:37:00", "2022-01-04 07:00:00", "2022-01-04 15:00:00", "2022-01-04 20:00:00", "2022-01-05 02:00:00", "2022-01-05 08:00:00")),
    day = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2,2),
    pain_score = c("None", "Mild", "Mild", "Moderate", "None", "Mild")
  )
```

When I use the following code, it creates a new variable where the last time difference is 6 hours (not 4):

```
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(patient_id, time) %>% 
  group_by(patient_id) %>% 
  mutate(time_diff_hours = as.numeric(lead(time) - time, units = 'hours'))
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

I would like the output to be like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Ben

EDIT: I have expanded the original code to include an extra row to see what I am after, with an additional desired output table. As you can see, where the time goes over midnight, it is broken up into 2 time points with the corresponding pain score with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ceiling_date` and `floor_date` functions from `lubridate` to make a sequence that registers every date at 00:00.

Then, by using `fill` from `tidyr` you can carry forward the previous values to the date at 00:00. An alternative would be to use `na.locf()` from the `zoo` package.

Finally, you can calculate the time difference between the next time and the previous one the way you were wishing. The last row remains as an `NA` because the lead function will not find another time forward.

I think this satisfies the requirements you had and seems to work.

```r
  df %>% complete(time = seq.POSIXt(min(ceiling_date(time , 'day')), 
                                    max(floor_date(time , 'day')), by = 'day')) %>% 
         arrange(time) %>%
         fill(c(patient_id, pain_score)) %>% fill(day, .direction = "up") %>%
         mutate(time_diff_hours = as.numeric(lead(time ) - time, units = 'hours'))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Is there a way to create another row that has the residual time before the next assessment? (i.e. having another row that has the 2 hours on day 2 with pain score of "None". Because of the ceiling_date and floor_date functions, when pain scores are assessed at midnight, a time difference of 0 comes up. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that if you have two measurements at 12:00 am it should count as 24 hours and instead is it showing zero? I provided an updated version calculating the residual time instead of using floor_date. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: This works for the dummy dataset I gave, but doesn't work for my own dataset.  Once the next assessment the following day is performed, there is no extra row with the residual pain scores and times.    
To answer your question, what is happening is that if the pain assessment is done at 0000, it is not calculating the lead(time) until the next assessment.

Comment: What is the value you expect to have for an assessment done at 0000?

Comment: Sorry, it's not calculating the time difference between midnight and the time of the next assessment.

Comment: Updated now. The problem is that the latest time in the database will have the same time difference in hours as the previous one. It is not a very elegant solution again but it might get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is better, but there is still the issue of the residual pain score from midnight to the next time point. I have edited the dataset and the desired output to show you what I mean.

Comment: I think now it solves it the way you were looking for.

Comment: It keeps throwing off an error (Error in ceiling_date(dttm, "day") : object 'dttm' not found)

Comment: Sorry, I changed the variable `time` to `dttm`. With the latest version of the code it should work. I changed it because `time()` is a built-in function of the package `stats` in R and I wanted to make sure I was not calling it. I would personally avoid naming variables that have the same name as other functions in R as a practice.

Comment: Ahhh! Gotcha. I've not used lubridate much before so am not experienced with time wrangling. Thanks so much for your help. You've saved my project!