# Calculating Time Differences Between Rows Where the Category Passes Over Midnight (Part 2)

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

This question is an extension of a previous question I asked ([Calculating Time Differences Between Rows Where the Category Passes Over Midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75292830/calculating-time-differences-between-rows-where-the-category-passes-over-midnigh)). Whilst the reponse to that post by [maupagas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21097868/maupagas) solved the problem with the reproducible example, when I tried it on a more complex dataset, some issues popped up.

I have a dataset that is comparing pain scores and am trying to determine the duration of time that the person is in a particular pain range. The idea is to treat each pain score as constant until the next time pain is assessed. What I want is a duration (`time_diff_hours`) of a particular pain range (`pain_score`) for each observed day (`day`).

The issues that I have encountered are:

1. When a pain score occurs after midnight, a new row was inserted starting from midnight and the new time epoch commenced there, with the previous `pain_score` carried over into the new day. This worked with the solved code from previously until there was more than one patient_id. The code arranged the variables by time, but should have been by `patient_id`, then `time`. I have not been able to code my way out of this.
2. When there are no pain assessments performed during a specific day. I would like to be able to generate a new row for that day with a 24 hour time difference (`time_diff_hours`) and the `pain_score` be NA.

I have included a dummy dataset that is similar to what I am using.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tibble(
    patient_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    time = lubridate::as_datetime(c("2022-01-04 02:00:00", "2022-01-04 07:00:00", "2022-01-04 15:00:00", "2022-01-04 20:00:00", "2022-01-06 02:00:00", "2022-01-06 08:00:00",
                                    "2022-01-04 04:00:00", "2022-01-04 14:00:00", "2022-01-04 22:00:00", "2022-01-05 02:00:00", "2022-01-05 20:00:00", "2022-01-06 12:00:00", "2022-01-06 18:00:00")),
    day = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3,3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
    pain_score = c("None", "Mild", "Mild", "Moderate", "None", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Moderate", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Moderate")
  )
```

Here is the code solution from the previous post:

```
df |>  complete(time = seq.POSIXt(min(ceiling_date(time , 'day')), 
                                  max(floor_date(time , 'day')), by = 'day')) |>  
  arrange(time) |> 
  fill(c(patient_id, pain_score)) |>  
  fill(day, .direction = "up") |> 
  mutate(time_diff_hours = as.numeric(lead(time ) - time, units = 'hours'))
```

This gives the following output:
[image]

As you can see, when a second `patient_id` is added, the `time_diff_hours` becomes negative (it would be good to have as a NA). Also, there is no NA for when a `pain_score` wasn't performed (ie missing data).

Here is what I want the output to look like:

[image]

Any help would be greaetly appreciated.

Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

```
bind_rows(df,
  df |>
  reframe(time = seq.POSIXt(
    ceiling_date(min(time), "day"), floor_date(max(time), "day"), "1 day"),
    .by = patient_id)) |>
  arrange(patient_id, time) |>
  mutate(day = as.numeric(as_date(time) - as_date(min(time)) + 1), 
         time_diff_hours = (lead(time) - time)/dhours(1),
         .by = patient_id)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 17 × 5
   patient_id time                  day pain_score time_diff_hours
        <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>
 1          1 2022-01-04 02:00:00     1 None                     5
 2          1 2022-01-04 07:00:00     1 Mild                     8
 3          1 2022-01-04 15:00:00     1 Mild                     5
 4          1 2022-01-04 20:00:00     1 Moderate                 4
 5          1 2022-01-05 00:00:00     2 NA                      24
 6          1 2022-01-06 00:00:00     3 NA                       2
 7          1 2022-01-06 02:00:00     3 None                     6
 8          1 2022-01-06 08:00:00     3 Mild                    NA
 9          2 2022-01-04 04:00:00     1 Moderate                10
10          2 2022-01-04 14:00:00     1 Severe                   8
11          2 2022-01-04 22:00:00     1 Moderate                 2
12          2 2022-01-05 00:00:00     2 NA                       2
13          2 2022-01-05 02:00:00     2 Mild                    18
14          2 2022-01-05 20:00:00     2 Moderate                 4
15          2 2022-01-06 00:00:00     3 NA                      12
16          2 2022-01-06 12:00:00     3 Severe                   6
17          2 2022-01-06 18:00:00     3 Moderate                NA
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Jon. The only problem is that the `pain_score` variables are not carried over from the day before when they are done jsut prior to midnight (in this case, row 12 & 15- these should both read Moderate).

Comment: Can you say more about what logic should make those moderate but keep row 5+6 as NA?

Comment: Row 5 and 6 should read NA as they would be missing values (ie pain has not been assessed in the previous day). The idea is that if pain is assessed at say 10pm and then at 2am, then I'd like to break that up into 2 time epochs (2200-2400 and 0000-0200). It will help with time in a certain pain category in a 24 hour period (which will be from 0000-2400).

Comment: Row 5 and row 15 both follow 8pm observations, what drives the distinction in treatment?

Comment: The distinction is that because there is no pain assessment on day 2 (for patient 1), it is more of an assumption of what the pain score is, especially given that it would be 30 hours between pain assessments. For row 15, it is easier to assume that the pain score would be similar to the previous one, especially given that a new value occurs 4 hours later.

Comment: Can you please specify a rule / threshold distinguishing when it becomes more of an assumption?

Comment: It would be that if there is no pain assessment on that day, it is an NA. Otherwise, the pain score on that day would be used (ie if `time_diff_hours==24`, then `pain_score==NA` (but the next time point (unless it started at 0000 would also be NA)).